# Python text editor with "programatically" typing capabilities

Tags: python, tkinter

I need a text editor which, as a feature, must have the capability of changing some of the information it shows on the screen, while open.

For example, I open the text file using that text editor mentioned above, and I can see on the screen:

```
|--------------------------------------------------------|
|          My Text Editor (C:\myfile.txt)    [Button]    |
|--------------------------------------------------------|
|Name: John                                              |
|Age: 32                                                 |
|Gender: Male                                            |
|                                                        | 
|                                                        |
```

Then, for example, if I hit the button `[Button]`, I want that the Age 32 change for, say, 30, while the text file is open.

But I want to do that without using keyboard and mouse automation...

Is that possible? Will Tkinter be enough for that task?

Comment: How do you plan on "hitting" the button without using the keyboard and mouse? What have you tried so far? Tkinter  has a text widget with methods that make it easy to change anything in the widget.

Comment: yes, tkinter is certainly up to this task.

Comment: Hello, Bryan, thanks for the reply. I am gonna use that for updating configuration files, so I can use the keyboard, but, instead of typing the information inside the text file all the time, I need to have both possibilities, I mean, update the file by typing new information, and by reading new information from another source (clipboard, text files, databases, etc), and then change the file that is open in front of me with that information read from others sources, as well as typing. Good to know that Tkinter can do it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a contrived example that both has a button to change the age, and also will update the time every second.

It does this with a [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) which preserves the insertion cursor and then inserts or deletes any text you want. This isn't particularly good coding style, but it shows what tkinter can do with its text widget.

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def preserve_insert_cursor(text):
    """Performs an action without changing the insertion cursor location"""
    saved_insert = text.index("insert")
    yield
    text.mark_set("insert", saved_insert)

def change_age():
    """Change the age on line 3"""
    with preserve_insert_cursor(text):
        text.delete("3.5", "3.0 lineend")
        text.insert("3.5", "30")

def update_time():
    with preserve_insert_cursor(text):
        # find all ranges of text tagged with "time" and replace
        # them with the current time
        now = datetime.now()
        timestring = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

        ranges = list(text.tag_ranges("time"))
        while ranges:
            start = ranges.pop(0)
            end = ranges.pop(0)
            text.delete(start, end)
            text.insert(start, timestring, "time")

    # call this function again in a second
    text.after(1000, update_time)

root = tk.Tk()
header = tk.Frame(root, bd=1, relief="raised")
text = tk.Text(root)
header.pack(side="top", fill="x")
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

button = tk.Button(header, text="Button", command=change_age)
button.pack(side="right", padx=10)

# insert "Time:" with no tags, "<time>" with the tag "time",
# and then a newline with no tags
text.insert("end", "Time: ", "", "<time>", "time", "\n")

text.insert("end", "Name: John\n")
text.insert("end", "Age: 32\n")
text.insert("end", "Gender: Male\n")

update_time()

root.mainloop()
```

You can't tell from a static screenshot, but if you run the code you'll see that the time updates in real time even while you're typing.
[image]

Comment: I'm always learning something new from you. I wouldn't have been able to write this that slick, in python. Excellent code, Bryan!

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best way to achieve this is to take a simple TextEditor example for PyQT and add a button to do what you want.

In a quick search I found for example this one:
https://www.learnpyqt.com/examples/no2pads-simple-notepad-clone/

Comment: Thank you, @cagcoach. Quickly looking, I see that the QPlainTextEdit Class and the QTextCursor Class seems they can do the job :)

Comment: Hello, @cagcoch. I had to change my chosen answer, since tkinter is gonna be my primary tool. But I am glad you showed us the power of PyQT!